# Get only the data when i execute a query in PostgreSQL

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

When I execute my query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT names 
from user;
```

I obtain the following result:

```
      names
--------------
Anna
Julius
Perico

(3 rows)
```

What I want to get is the following output:

```
Anna Julius Perico
```

I need this because is a bash script ant I need to save it in a variable.

Comment: Hi @Marco can you provide the schema of your table?

Comment: Not sure what the difference between the two alternatives is, but you can also use `psql -A -t` to get rid of the column header and the `(3 rows)` feedback.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I want. The final command i have used is  psql -A -t -d users -c  \" select names from user \"" postgres

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use it in a shell script, this would be the best way:

```
myvar=`psql --no-align --quiet --tuples-only --command='SELECT name FROM users'`
```

No need to have them in one line; the shell accepts a line feed as field separator as well:

```
for n in $myvar; do
    echo "name: $n"
done

name: Anna
name: Julius
name: Perico
```

Answer (score 1):

The `string_agg` function *might* be what you want here:

```
select string_agg(names, ' ' order by names) from user;
```

I said "might" because this assumes that the `names` column itself could be used to generate the order in the single string output.  If you want a different order, then you would need another column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name These multiple edits are really `AGG`revating for me :-(